# External IP from kubectl is taking forever to get assigned

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, service, ip, cloud

```bash
NAMESPACE     NAME             TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
default       kubernetes       ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP                  2d8h
default       mongo-service    ClusterIP      10.108.211.111   <none>        27017/TCP                45h
default       my-service       LoadBalancer   10.98.217.118    <pending>     8080:30941/TCP           20m
default       webapp-service   LoadBalancer   10.97.145.165    <pending>     3000:30100/TCP           45h
kube-system   kube-dns         ClusterIP      10.96.0.10       <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   2d8h
```

You can see it has taken more than 2 days to get assigned. I don't know what's wrong.

I was creating a simple kubernetes deployment and service but it is taking forever to assign it a external ip address.

Comment: I guess you're running kubernetes locally with something like minikube. With this setup the external ip will never be set, except you use something like metallb.

Answer (score 0):

In Kubernetes, LoadBalancer Service uses an external Load Balancer provided by your infrastructure. So, if your infrastructure does not provide the Load Balancer External IP, you'll see `<pending>` forever.

As a side note, this might be the case with the default configuration in minikube.

Comment: Can you describe how to assign it external ip

Comment: What do you use for Kubernetes? Minikube?

Comment: Yes, I use miniikube

Comment: `minikube tunnel` should work. You can check more here: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/#example-of-loadbalancer